# Is a linear map $T:\mathbb R^4→M_{2\times2}(\mathbb R)$ unique given $Im(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given $T:\mathbb R^4→M_{2\times2}(\mathbb R)$ and $Im(T)$ as a span of three specific linearly independent matrices $A_1, A_2, A_3$, can we say that such a map is unique?

I think we cannot. I got to the part where I show that there are infinitely many linear maps s.t. $A_1, A_2, A_3$ belong to $Im(T)$, but I'm not sure how I can prove that there are infinitely many linear maps whose image is spanned by $A_1, A_2, A_3$. I thought about using $\dim(\mathbb R^4)=\dim(Im(T))+\dim(Ker(T))$, therefore, $\dim(Ker(T))=1$, but I don't know how to continue from there.

Is there a way I can finish my proof, or should I use a completely different approach?

Comment: Why not try a constructive approach? Let T send the first three standard basis elements to A1, A2, and A3. What can you send the fourth basis element to?

Comment: @ElchananSolomon to a linear combination of  A1, A2, and A3?

Comment: @user3734 Yes, to **any** linear combination of $A_1,A_2,A_3$. All you need to say, then, is that there is more than one such linear combination and that this means that there is more than one map with this image.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you, now I understand :)

Comment: @user3734, yes exactly as Ben explained.